# Magento best practices: try / catch in templates

Tags: magento2, template, best-practice, template-directive

I have a question about best practices in templates.

Let's assume I am editing the product details template file. I would like to call a method in the product model which can raise an exception.

What is the best way to proceed :

- to put the call in a verbose try / catch in the template, displaying the appropriate result in case of success/failure ;

> ```
> try {
>     echo $product->getSomething()->getName();
> } catch (NoSuchEntityException $ex) {
>     echo "No related Something";
> } catch (\Exception $ex)) {
>     echo "An error occured while extracting the related Something";
> }
> ```

- or creating an intermediate method (in the block ?), handling the try catch and returning and array with the result (if success) and a possible message, to make the template cleaner?

> ```
> $result = $block->getSomething();
> if($result['message'] === "") { // Everything went well
>     echo $result['Something']->getName();
> } else { // Something went wrong
>     echo $result['message'];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion templates don't have to contain any logic on that point.
If we take your exemple, the best way is to make the `try / catch` in the block, the template is here only to display data.

**Block file**
<?php
class Foo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
[...]
public function getName()
{
[...]
try {
return $product->getSomething()->getName();
} catch (NoSuchEntityException $ex) {
$this->logger->critical($ex);
return false;
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
$this->logger->critical($ex);
return false;
}
}
}

**Template file**

```
<?php
/** @var string|false $name */
$name = $block->getName();
?>

[...]
<?php if ($name): ?>
   // logic...
<?php endif; ?>
```

In your case you can imagine different types of return in your block function and test them on your template to display the right information.

Comment: Exactly this. Templates should be as dumb as possible and only do stuff like `if`, `else`, `echo` and first-class `$block`-methods. Anything else is not the responsibility of the template and breaks the S.O.L.I.D. principle at that point. The only responsibility a template has is render data to HTML, not the logic that determines what the data is or if it should be rendered (example: `<?php if ($block->hasName()) : ?><h1><?php echo $block->getName(); ?></h1><?php endif; ?>`)